# "Анаграммы" из массива. Java.Рекурсия в цикле

Tags: java

Решил задачу представленную здесь:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJCgFbb_qWA&list=PLoij6udfBncjOlB-3LfW9kVPAjr1-fqx9&index=4 
с помошью подсказки  в комментариях))))Не до конца понимаю, что происходит.Можите пояснить. **Задача была дописать код чтобы он правильно составлял "Анаграммы", сохранив идею.** Не понимаю как эта строка (решение) спасло ситуацию, почему и как это объясняется тем ,что идёт движение обратно по стеку.

Исходный код:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Permutator {

public static void permute (int[] arr, int size){
    if( size < 2){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    } else { 
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++){
            swap(arr, k, size-1);
            permute(arr, size-1);

        }
    }
}
private static void swap(int [] arr, int index0, int index1 ){
int tmp = arr[index0];
arr[index0] = arr[index1];
arr[index1] = tmp;
}
}
```

Итог(при исходном массиве [1, 2, 3]) :
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 3]

Код(то что с комментарием и есть решение):

```
package chapterfirst;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Permutator {

    public static void permute (int[] arr, int size){
        if( size < 2){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        } else { 
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++){
                swap(arr, k, size-1);
                permute(arr, size-1);
                swap(arr, k, size-1); //решение
            }
        }
    }
    private static void swap(int [] arr, int index0, int index1 ){
    int tmp = arr[index0];
    arr[index0] = arr[index1];
    arr[index1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Результат(при исходном массиве [1, 2, 3]):
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 1):

Лучше объяснить с помощью индукции.

Если size равен 1 элемент, то метод распечатает массив.

Если 2  - мы возьмем первый элемент и поменяем его местами со вторым, и попробуем повторить тоже самое, но уже на подмассиве длины 1. Здесь получили случай 1.

Если N, то произойдет следующее, поочередно будем доставать из массива элементы с индексами от 0 до N, менять их местами с последним элементом и вызывать аналогичную процедуру, но уже на подмассиве размером N-1. После вызова, мы возвращаем элементы на прежние места.